# Spell-check in Atom in xml files

Tags: xml, atom-editor, spell-checking

Does somebody know how to check for spelling mistakes only in xml files ?

For example I have the following code :

```
<trans-unit id="95ddf1ed4481c0a4c1621121464c81aa" resname="button.next">
    <source>button.next</source>
    <target>Next</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I would like the spell checker to check only `Next`and **not anything else**...

I already tried to add the `text.xml` scope in the spell checker config and it checks every string.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `spell-check` accepts more refined scopes, such as `text.xml meta.tag.xml punctuation.definition.tag.xml`, but only the scope for the entire syntax (e.g. `text.xml`).

From the spell-check README:

> To enable *Spell Check* for your current file type: put your cursor in
>   the file, open the [Command
>   Palette](https://github.com/atom/command-palette)
>   (<kbd>cmd-shift-p</kbd>), and run the `Editor: Log Cursor Scope`
>   command. This will trigger a notification which will contain a list of
>   scopes. The first scope that's listed is the one you should add to the
>   list of scopes in the settings for the *Spell Check* package.